# Tensorflow: Convert Save_mode.pb to a freeze_graph.pb with Tensorflow 2.5.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, freeze

I recently trained my own custom object detector model using mobilenetssd as my pretrained model. I have been following this [tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#exporting-a-trained-model) to train my model, and used exporter_main_v2.py program in TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection/ to generate my save_model.pb file. I would like to use OpenCV DNN module where it requires a frozen model and the pbtext. In order to generate the pbtext file, I would need to convert it from the frozen_graph.pb. I would like to convert my save_model.pb to a frozen_graph.pb file, but it looks like freezing graphs has been deprecated in tensorflow 2.X. I tried this [solution](https://medium.com/@sebastingarcaacosta/how-to-export-a-tensorflow-2-x-keras-model-to-a-frozen-and-optimized-graph-39740846d9eb) but I get this error:

`AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'inputs'`
Does anyone have recommendations or solutions on how I can covert my save_model.pb to a freeze_graph.pb? I would really appreciate the help!